# Need help copying a char array into an array struct with char pointer

Tags: pointers, struct, char, copy

I'm trying to copy char array word to char pointer `s[1].c`, an then another word to char pointer `s[2].c` but when i'm trying to do that , the second word appears to be copied in all two pointers . How can i fix that ? I don't want to use strings .

```
struct Stud {
  char *c;
} s[100];
char word[32];

int main()
{
  strcpy(word,"one");
  s[1].c=word;
  word={0};
  strcpy(word,"two");
  s[2].c=word;
  cout<<s[1].c<<" "<<s[2].c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the address of word never changes. You can use [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Ok. Don't forget to [`free`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) the memory.

Comment: Can you explain me how exactly should i use strdup ?

Comment: Never mind . I wrote s[1].c=strdup(word); s[2].c=strdup(word); and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting `s[1].c = word;` which means you are setting s[1].c to the address of word. Then you set `s[2].c = word;` which is the same exact memory location. (With c strings, `(char *)s1 = (char *)2` does not do a string copy as you might expect. It just assigns one pointer to another).

With `strdup` you allocate a new memory block and then copy the string into the allocated space.

Here's your code modified.

```
struct Stud
{
    char *c;
} s[100];

int main()
{
    char word[32];
    strcpy(word, "one");
    s[0].c = strdup(word);   // In C/C++ the first array index is 0
    strcpy(word, "two");
    s[1].c = strdup(word);

    // Should check to make sure s[0].c and s[1].c are not NULL....

    cout << s[0].c << " " <<s [1].c;

    free(s[0].c);
    free(s[1].c);

    return 0;
}
```